# How to build Slack clone using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat, slack

We are building a slack clone, where could be many organizations, which each organization have multiple rooms or channels like slack.

I have 2-3 mongo models to save messages:

```
model conversations{
    id: Int
    participants:[userIds]
    date:Date
    lastMessage:Message
}


model message {
    id:Int
    body:String
    conversationId: Conversation
    date:Date
}

model User {
   id:Int
   name:Sting
   organisationId:Organisation
}

model Organisation {
  id:Int
  name:String
}
```

Each organization can have many rooms/ channel and the user can be in that room/channel.

I'm thinking to use `new socket.io namespace` for each organization.  Each namespace im using `socket.io rooms` as channels, where users can subscribe to rooms and communicate

I'm not sure how the client will create namespace for each organization, how in each namespace can create rooms as there is no room concept in `socket.io` client side.

I just want someone who can help me understand how can i implement namespaces and rooms in socket from client and also on server side.

I know how to listen to events and and send to events in general, but not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I remember I made an online game with socket.io.
The flow was simple, some user was able to create their own room and some of them was able to join their rooms.
I think you should use this method. By creating a channel by an Organization or a user, you should start listening to the room.
the namespace should be the name of the room.